# Remove MS CRM 2011 plugin step programmatically

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I try to remove plugin step in this way:

```
public void RemoveStep(Guid stepId, IOrganizationService service){        
service.Execute(new SetStateRequest 
{
    EntityMoniker = new EntityReference("sdkmessageprocessingstep", stepId),
    State = new OptionSetValue(pluginStateCode),
    Status = new OptionSetValue(pluginStatusCode)
});}
```

But this code throw fault exception with message: Invalid plug-in stage.
What is wrong?
And how I can do it?

Comment: What are you passing as pluginStateCode and pluginStatusCode? Try it with State = 1 and Status = 2 hardcoded.

Comment: Hello! Sorry for not said about it, in pluginStateCode I pass 1, and in pluginStatusCode I pass 2. By the way exception occurs. And one remark:I try to do that from my code, not from plugin.

Comment: Invalid plugin stage means that the plugin registration was configured incorrectly. The weird part is that you usually get that exception while registering a plugin step, not while unregistering it. Could you update your question with following information: Entity on which the step is executed; Pipeline Stage; Event that triggers the step.

Comment: Nate, I can't answer your questions, I retrieve ids of all steps in system. My goal is delete all steps from system, so I try to do folowing: retrieve ids of all steps, then I want to disable steps and then I would line to delete theme. I do it from WinForms application not from plug-in

Comment: Does it fail on the first plugin it comes across no matter what that plugin is, or does it fail on a specific plugin step?

Comment: It fails on first plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

You need to pass a valid state and status code mapping, these are the values that are permitted for SdkMessageProcessingStep quoting the sdk

> statecode:  0 - Enabled.
>                 1 - Disabled.
>
> statuscode: 1 - Enabled.
>                 2 - Disabled.

And you should map according to this:

> statecode 0 and statuscode 1
>
> statecode 1 and statuscode 2

With the correct values you should not have problems setting the state.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was coused because I have tried to change state for steps of system's plug-ins, so it is not possible.